# Customer’s IT refuses set up SPF

Tags: dns, spf

I train customers how to use Emarketing tools. One important thing I tell them they have to do is have their IT set their Email domain DNS to allow the emarketing domains to send on their behalf via an SPF record and I give them most all the settings. Until this one current client where their IT is refusing to create one. My understanding is if they don’t, at minimum, all their Emarketing emails will basically all go to junk/spam or even get them blacklisted in places. So... is there a potential downside to making an SPF record that would make this person so adamantly against creating one?

Comment: Though I answered this Q, this is way off topic for SO - better to ask on Server Fault, though it's also likely to get downvoted as "primarily opinion-based, which it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main downside of making an SPF record that actually helps deliverability (by confining mail sources) is that you have to know and limit the sources from which email may be sent, and that's not necessarily easy.

Say your domain is example.com and you want to send email *from* that domain using your gmail account (though gmail is not used to handle your domains email); your SPF would need to include gmail's SPF, and it therefore means that *anyone* on gmail gets to be able to send in your domain's name from gmail (other measures notwithstanding). Now imagine you're a big company and you have a long history of having employees routinely send email from company addresses using their local ISP. Your SPF needs to become very large, or very dumb, and includes so many email sources it becomes ineffective as a countermeasure.

Reluctance to have to deal with user complaints when you say that all outbound mail *must* go through company mail servers (when you have a long history of not requiring that) would be painful for a lazy IT support department. I have no sympathy for this policy - you reap what you sow.

You can of course have an SPF record "in name only" by having it set to something useless like `+all` - that would get a technical SPF "pass" for all sources, but in all other respects it's completely useless, marking fraudulent, spam & phishing messages as equally valid as legit email.

Any IT department that wilfully ignores the benefits of SPF is eventually going to have a major problem with deliverability and phishing, so you can reasonably argue they are failing to do their job, and I'd recommend reporting them to higher management.

Comment: Thank you!  Appreciate the in depth answer!